# How does cpanel create accounts?

Tags: php, node.js, server, cpanel, user-accounts

Say I don't want cpanel to create websites/accounts on a server.
Is there a way to create them programmatically, like in nodejs or PHP ?
How does cpanel do it?

I know that websites are created by modifying the apache config files, but how to add accounts and link them to websites?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel and other control panels aren't very simple to explain in a single StackOverflow question in my opinion.

Trying to put it simpler, it consists in a process of:

1. creating a user on the operating system;
2. creating the skeleton folders;
3. assigning the right permissions;
4. assigning the right account limits;
5. creating a virtual host in apache;
6. configuring internal dns entries;
7. creating a user in its database so they can login later;
8. send confirmation emails about account creation;

These are some basic steps required to make a system like cPanel add a new account. There are probably many more that I'm not thinking of.